# how to change style in table row if the available quantity column is equals 10

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

Is it possible in `AngularJS` to change the style of row when the available stocks is equals to 10? or is there any way to do this?.. how to do that?

[image]

Here's my code..

```
<table id='table12'>
    <thead id='top'>
        <tr>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Stock In</th>
            <th>Available Stocks</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="clickrow" ng-repeat="inventory in data | filter:searchFilter">
            <td onclick="showDialog()" ng-click="showInEdit(inventory)">{{inventory.product_id}}</td>
            <td onclick="showDialog()" ng-click="showInEdit(inventory)">{{inventory.product_name}}</td>
            <td onclick="showDialog()" ng-click="showInEdit(inventory)">{{inventory.price}}</td>
            <td onclick="showDialog()" ng-click="showInEdit(inventory)">{{inventory.stock_in}}</td>
            <td onclick="showDialog()" ng-click="showInEdit(inventory)">{{inventory.available_stocks}}</td>
            <td onclick="showDialog()" ng-click="showInEdit(inventory)">{{inventory.description}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ng-class should do the trick, share your code for more help.

Comment: i looked up for the ng-class and try it to my code. and it works :) thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with ng-class by passing an object with a test against inventory.price value:

```
<tr id="clickrow" ng-repeat="inventory in data | filter:searchFilter" ng-class="{'red' : inventory.price <= 10}">
    ...
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change style of row with anulgarJS via html markup and via js code:

1. markup -

   1.1. **ng-style**: `<div data-ng-style="{background: price > 50 ? 'red' : 'green'}"></div>`

   1.2. **ng-class**: `<div data-ng-class="{'some-class-name': price > 50, 'other-class-name': price <= 50}></div>`
2. js code -

   2.1. directive **link** function:

   `link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
      element.find('tr').css(...); // like as jquery...
   }`

   2.2. **controller**:

   ```
   angular.module('myModule').controller('myCtrl', function($element, $scope){ $element.find('tr').css(...); // like as jquery}  })
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr ng-repeat="task in todos"
                ng-class="{'warning': task.status == 'Hold' , 'success': task.status == 'Completed',
              'active': task.status == 'Started', 'danger': task.status == 'Pending' } "></tr>
```

You can use above syntax to highlight table rows